# How can I emulate SQL projection in C++?

Tags: c++, database

Say, I have a class:

```
class Person {
    std::string name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
    int wage;
};
```

and a table filled with many `Person`s.

I want to take 3th, 4th "columns" to create a new table. That is, if we have something like:

```
{"Obama", 60, 178, 72, 3000},
{"Trump", 70, 185, 120, 4000},
{"Biden", 80, 180, 90, 5000},
```

then I want to take a table like:

```
{178, 72},
{185, 120},
{180, 90}
```

The example above is just an example, I cannot create a newly created instance. Some of the class member variables are expensive to copy, so I want to have a table of non-owning references.

Is there any way to make an API like `extract({3, 4})` in C++?

Comment: This will be very hard to get working type-wise. How do you tell C++ that `extract({3,4}}` has rows of type `(int, int)`, but `extract({0,1,2})` has rows of type `(string, int, int)`? Or are the column numbers known at compile time?

Comment: @Botje Yes, this is a hard job. That's why I asked this here. I'm working with ```std::forward_as_tuple``` but I'm stucked.

Comment: Is a solution involving `std::variant` allowed? That does mean you have to know the list of types up front, though.

Comment: Yes, the types of class member variables are known in advance. Actually, I have only one class to deal with (but a large number of class member variables, admittedly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I cobbled together. The core part is a `Value` type, based on `std::variant`. Printing values is done through `std::visit`.

```
using Value = std::variant<int, std::reference_wrapper<const std::string>>;
struct ValuePrinter {
    std::ostream* os;
    void operator()(int v) { *os << v; }
    void operator()(std::reference_wrapper<const std::string> v) { *os << v.get(); }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Value& v) {
    std::visit(ValuePrinter{&os},v);
    return os;
}
```

The `extract` function is simple, then:

```
Value getter(const Person& p, int i) {
  if (i == 0) return p.name;
  if (i == 1) return p.age;
  if (i == 2) return p.height;
  if (i == 3) return p.weight;
  if (i == 4) return p.wage;
  throw -1;
}

std::vector<Value> extract(const Person& p, std::vector<int> indices) {
  std::vector<Value> ret;
  for (int idx : indices)
     ret.emplace_back(getter(p, idx));

  return ret;
}
```